# Read binary file in python based on some structure

Tags: python, struct, binary, decode, binaryfiles

I have a binary file that was created using some cpp code ans structures. Now, I want to read the content of this file in python. I am using the struct module to do the same. But some byte code are strange and I have no idea of how to unpack them. The sample code is shown below. What should be the format_string for bytes like '\x05E' ?

also, it would be great if someone can tell me the significance of @ and & with respect to packed data.

Code:

```
format_string = 'i'

packed_data=b'\x05E\xd4\x17\xcd'
unpacked_data = struct.unpack(format_string, packed_data)

print('Packed data:', packed_data)
print('Unpacked data:', unpacked_data)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 14, in <module>
struct.error: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I tried using different formats listed at https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html
None worked for me.

Comment: Look at the length of *packed_data* and you'll see that it's 5 bytes. '\x05E' is 2 bytes - i.e., ENQ + E

Comment: actually, you can only do that if you have the original C/C++ struct to know the length of each field. Either that or some reverse engineering: i.e. some sample data for which you have the encoded bytes and can check the numbers you read back from it. As it is, you can have several combinations  5 8 bit numbers, or 3 8 bit + 1 16 bit, or 1 bit + 1 32bit, etc...and each number might be signed or unsigned.